# Playa or Assets issues with php 5.3.20 and above

Tags: assets, playa

Cannot render an Assets tag pair inside a Playa field on a live server using php 5.4.13 EE just cannot recognize from the Playa tag pairs inwards. Using a single tag it works like always.

just to be more clear:
*** this doesn't work with php 5.4.10 and above ***

```
{prodotti_correlati_manutenzione dynamic="no"}
                                                    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 column">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="small-12 column">
                                                                <a href="{page_url}">{exp:ce_img:single src="{img_prodotto}" width="200" height="200" crop="yes"}</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="small-12 column">
                                                                <a href="{page_url}">{title}</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                {/prodotti_correlati_manutenzione}
```

*** this doesn't work with php 5.3.20 and above ***

```
{prodotti_correlati_manutenzione dynamic="no"}
                                                <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 column">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="small-12 column">
                                                            {img_prodotto}
                                                                <a href="{page_url}">
                                                                    {exp:ce_img:single src="{url}" width="200" height="200" crop="yes"}
                                                                </a>
                                                            {/img_prodotto}
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="small-12 column">
                                                            <a href="{page_url}">{title}</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            {/prodotti_correlati_manutenzione}
```

EE 2.7.3
Playa 4.4.5
Assets 2.2.4
Structure 3.3.14
Transcribe 1.6

bye
Thanks

Comment: tried using exp:playa:children with var_prefix as suggested by @piparvecis but still no luck

Comment: tried using {exp:playa:children  field="prodotti_correlati_manutenzione"} but still works on local but not on live server here I get the name of the parent entry x times

Answer (score 2):

We just came across a very similar issue where an Assets tag pair was not being parsed in one environment but was working fine in others while single tags were working fine everywhere. The solution for us turned out to be that we had to bump up the pcre.backtrack_limit value in the php.ini to 1000000 on the server where the tags weren't being parsed. It looks like that value needs to be set pretty high when there are templates with a lot of nested tags.